# session user sometimes has value sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I have a little problem, and I have already spent one day trying to solve it with no results. I used passport.js, and the login and session work well, if I access address without login then I will be kicked to login page. But I have a little problem, when I fill datasource of datatable (**cart.html**) with routing from **index.js**, **req.session.user** will be undefined. But I checked in **cart.html** in routing of **index.js**, it has a value. I would appreciate anyone who can help me, thanks in advance.

Here is my routing **cart.html** of **index.js**

```
app.get('/cart',(req,res)=>{
    //res.render('cart');
    if (req.session.user) {
        var userdata=req.session.passport.user;
        res.render('cart',{username: userdata[0].USER,level:userdata[0].IDLEVEL});
    }else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

here my passport :

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: true},
    function(req,username, password, done) {
        db.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            SQL="SELECT * FROM muser WHERE USER = ? and PASSWORD = ?";
            connection.query(SQL, [username, password], function (err, rows) {
                connection.release();
                if(err) return done(err);

                // if user not found
                if (rows.length <= 0) {
                    return done('Cannot login');
                    //console.log(username+' '+password);
                }
                req.session.user=rows;
                return done(null, rows);
            });
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM muser WHERE ID = ?', [id], function(err, user) {
            connection.release();

            if(err) return done(err);
            done(null, user);
        });
    });
});

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
}

app.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.redirect('/home');
        }else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }
);
```

here my **cart.html**'s codes

```
            $("#dgcart").DataGrid({
                dataSource: "http://192.168.10.120:5556/getcart" (routing below to get data of cart)
...});
```

here my bug cannot access **req.session.user** will be undefined

```
app.get('/getcart',(req,res)=>{
    if (req.session.user) {
        var userdata=req.session.passport.user;
        SQL="SELECT TC.ID,TC.IDITEM,TC.KODEBARANG,TC.NAMA,SUM(TC.QTY) AS QTY,TC.PRICE, TC.SUBTOTAL"+'\n'+
            "FROM cart TC "+'\n'+
            "WHERE TC.IDUSER="+userdata[0].ID+'\n'+
            "GROUP BY TC.KODEBARANG,TC.IDITEM,TC.KODEBARANG,TC.NAMA,TC.PRICE,TC.SUBTOTAL,TC.IDUSER";
        rowsalasql=alasql(SQL);
        console.log(SQL+' '+rowsalasql);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(rowsalasql));
    }else {
        ... will be here because undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: did you tried     if (req.session.passport.user) {     in your  "/getCart" function ?

Comment: also same undefined, strange